# Where do I call my function so it successfully updates my UI?

Tags: swift

I have written the following function to ensure my user fills in a textField before being able to continue.

```
func validateFields() -> String {


    if textfield.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" {
        return "Please fill in textField"
    } 

    return "A-OK."
}

 func updateUI() {
    let verdict = validateFields()

    if verdict == "A-OK." {
        self.buttonOne.alpha = 1
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     updateUI()
}
```

However, once the textField has been filled in, the above code fails to update the UI. I know I am missing out on something trivial here, I just cannot wrap my head around what. I'd really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use text **textFieldDidEndEditing, textFieldDidBeginEditing, textFieldShouldReturn,** etc. according to your requirement.

But I think delegate "***textFieldShouldReturn***" works fine with your requirement.

You just need to add you function **updateUI()** in this delegate.

Answer (score 0):

> That's easy you can create an outlet of your text fields and give its
>   delegate to self in `viewDidLoad()` method

```
@IBOutlet var txtfld: UITextField!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    txtfld.delegate = self
 }

 // UITextField Delegates
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print("TextField did begin editing method called")
    }
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print("TextField did end editing method called")
    }
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print("TextField should begin editing method called")
        return true;
    }
    func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print("TextField should clear method called")
        return true;
    }
    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print("TextField should end editing method called")
        return true;
    }
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        print("While entering the characters this method gets called")
        return true;
    }
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print("TextField should return method called")
        textField.resignFirstResponder();
        return true;
    }
}
```

> I suggest for calling your method you should use your `updateUI()`
>   function in `textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField)` this
>   method.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you can easily bind you text view to a local property and observer changes on that property. And when everything is valid, you can enable your `buttonOne` and use the value of that property in future computations.

```
var myTextFieldData: String {
    didSet {
        updateUI()
    }
}
```

Also, keep in mind that you'll also have to implement the `UITextField` delegate in order to bind your `textField` with `myTextFieldData`:

```
textField.delegate = self

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    myTextFieldData = string
    return true
}
```